# Data to SQL Server "Float"

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, excel

I'm using Python to grab a generated report, clean the file up, format it, and then send it to the SQL Server for housing and to push to Tableau after.

The error is in a FirstName column where I have a float object.

> 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

The problem line of code is:

```
df[['FirstName', 'Business_Title']] = df['FirstName'].astype(str).str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

This is the code I am using:

```
df[['FirstName', 'Business_Title']] = df['FirstName'].astype(str).str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

I have previously tried using:

- `df[['FirstName', 'Business_Title']] = df['FirstName'].str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)`
- `df[['FirstName', 'Business_Title']] = df['FirstName'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).rsplit(' ', 1)) if pd.notna(x) and isinstance(x, str) else pd.Series([x, '']))`

Thank you for any assistance.

This is the whole code I am working with (with PII covered)(The problem line is block quoted)

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

def read_and_split_name(file_path, server_name, database_name):
    try:
        # Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame, skip the first 4 rows, and use the 5th row as the header
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=4)

        # Split the "Name" column into "First Name" and "Last Name" based on the comma
        df[['LastName', 'FirstName']] = df['Rendering'].astype(str).str.split(', ', 1, expand=True)

        # Further split the "First Name" column by spaces and add a new column "Business_Title"
        # Handle non-string values by converting them to strings
        df['FirstName'] = df['FirstName'].astype(str)
> df[['FirstName', 'Business_Title']] = df['FirstName'].astype(str).str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)
> 
        # Use transform('nunique') to get the count of unique values for each group
        df['_Unique'] = df.groupby(['Loc Name', 'LastName', 'FirstName'])['Enc Dt'].transform('nunique')

        # Use transform('count') to get the total count for each group
        df['_ENC'] = df.groupby(['Loc Name', 'LastName'])['Enc Dt'].transform('count')

        # Drop rows where last name is 'Nurse' or 'Enabling'
        df = df[~df['LastName'].isin(['Nurse', 'Enabling'])]

        # Replace spaces and dashes with underscores in the "Loc Name" column
        df['Loc Name'] = df['Loc Name'].str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('-', '_')

        # Calculate the new column "ENC_Per_"
        df['ENC_Per_'] = df['_ENC'] / df['_Unique']

        # Replace non-finite values (NA or inf) with a suitable replacement (e.g., 0)
        df['_Unique'] = df['_Unique'].fillna(0).astype(int)
        df['_ENC'] = df['_ENC'].fillna(0).astype(int)
        df['ENC_Per_'] = df['ENC_Per_'].fillna(0).astype(int)

        # Extract the month part of the date in MMM format
        df['MMM_Format'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Enc Dt'], errors='coerce', format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%b')

        # Convert the month abbreviations to uppercase
        df['MMM_Format'] = df['MMM_Format'].str.upper()

        # Update column headers based on the formatted month
        df.rename(columns={
            '_ENC': f"{df['MMM_Format'][0]}_ENC",
            'ENC_Per_': f"ENC_Per_{df['MMM_Format'][0]}",
            '_Unique': f"{df['MMM_Format'][0]}_Unique"
        }, inplace=True)

        # Export the DataFrame to a Microsoft SQL Server table using pyodbc
        conn_str = f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server_name};DATABASE={database_name};Trusted_Connection=yes;"
        with pyodbc.connect(conn_str) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                table_name = row['Loc Name'].replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_')  # Use Loc Name as the table name
                update_query = f"""
                    UPDATE {table_name}
                    SET FirstName = '{row['FirstName']}',
                        LastName = '{row['LastName']}',
                        Business_Title = '{row['Business_Title']}',
                        {row['MMM_Format']}_Unique = {row[f"{row['MMM_Format']}_Unique"]},
                        {row['MMM_Format']}_ENC = {row[f"{row['MMM_Format']}_ENC"]}
                    WHERE FirstName = '{row['FirstName']}' AND LastName = '{row['LastName']}'
                """
                cursor.execute(update_query)

        print("Update to SQL Server successful.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Specify the path to your .xls Excel file
file_path = "FILEPATH"

# Specify SQL Server connection details
server_name = "SERVERNAME"
database_name = "DATABASENAME"

# Call the function to read, split names, replace spaces and dashes, calculate new column, convert to integers, update column headers, and update SQL Server
read_and_split_name(file_path, server_name, database_name)
```

Comment: You reeally need to sort out that SQL injection, it's **dangerous**.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly declaring dtypes on read allow using `.str.rsplit` without casting:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=4, 
          dtype={'FirstName': str})
```

Since your error is regarding `replace` however, I don't think these lines are your issue. There are two lines that reference replace without casting:

```
27: df['Loc Name'] = df['Loc Name'].str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('-', '_')
55: table_name = row['Loc Name'].replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_')
```

You can include `'Loc Name':str` in the dtype dictionary to check if these are the issue.